# Dell 2100 with Intel WiFi 5100 on lubuntu 16.04. How do I install the correct WiFi driver

Tags: wireless

I'm new to Linux and am trying lubuntu on an old Dell laptop. I just can't get the WiFi to work. Machine says no WiFi connections available and no SSIDs seen. WiFi enabled in network settings and BIOS.  I've looked at the related posts by can't make sense of what I need to do to to install the correct driver. ..  assuming that is the issue. Any advice would be gratefully received.   Geoff

Comment: The correct driver is already installed in 16.04. If it isn't working, something else is wrong. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I am very grateful for your reply.  With your advice I stopped blaming the driver and eventually found a hidden hardware switch that was the source of the issue.  All good now and thanks again.